# Troubles with binding drawable icons in dropdown in MVVMCross Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, mvxbind

I need to add pictures to dropdown items.
In the dropdown I need to see the icon first and the text below. But for some reason, I can't see images, though I see the empty place instead.

My project is Xamarin.Android with MVVMCross. I'm missing something, maybe I need some plugins?

I have `MypageView.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        local:MvxBind="Text Strings[CityTextView]" />
    <MvxSpinner
        android:id="@+id/select_city"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_below="@id/city"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_city"
        local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/item_city"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Cities; SelectedItem SelectedCity" />
```

And `item_city.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cityImage"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        local:MvxBind="DrawableName Name, Converter=IconsConverter" /> />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cityName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cityImage"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the Core, I have `City.cs`:

```
namespace My.cities.Core.Models
{
    public class City
    {
        public City(string Id, string Name, string Flag)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Flag = Flag;
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Flag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And `MypageViewModel.cs`:

```
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using My.cities.Core.Models;

namespace My.cities.Core.ViewModels
{

    public class MypageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

    private City _selectedCity;

    private List<City> _cities = new List<City>()
    {
        new City("1", "London", "England")
        new City("2", "Paris", "France")
    };

    public List<City> Cities
    {
        get { return _cities; }
    }

    public City SelectedCity
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCity;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedCity = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedCity);
        }
    }
}
}
```

So I add the converter to `MypageView.cs`:

```
using Android.App;
using MvvmCross.Platform.Converters;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace My.cities.Droid.Views
{   [Activity]
    class MypageView : BaseView
    {
        protected override int LayoutResource => Resource.Layout.MypageView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        }

        public static class CrossDeviceInfoHelper
        {
            public static string GetLocalImageUrlByPlatform(string name)
            {

                return CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Platform == Platform.Android ? $"@drawable/{name}" : name;
            }
        }

        public class IconsConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, string>
        {
            protected override string Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value == "London")
        return CrossDeviceInfoHelper.GetLocalImageUrlByPlatform("england");
                if (value == "Paris")
        return CrossDeviceInfoHelper.GetLocalImageUrlByPlatform("france");
         }
    }
```

Images `England.png` and `France.png` live here: `My.sities.Droid\Resources\drawable-hdpi`, `My.sities.Droid\Resources\drawable-mdpi`, and etc.

The build is successful, but I can't see my images, only empty rectangles. Why?

UPD.

I installed `Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo` and changed my code. But I still can't see icons.

In debug it says:

```
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 36,05 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 36,06 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 36,06 Value 'London' was not a known drawable name
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 36,08 Value 'Paris' was not a known drawable name
```

UPD2.
Also, I tried to do it this way:

```
public class IconsConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, int>
        {
            protected override int Convert(string value, Type targetType, 
object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "London":
                        return Resource.Mipmap.England;
                    case "Paris":
                        return Resource.Mipmap.France;
                }
            }
        }
```

But the error is the same:

[0:] MvxBind:Warning:  9,54 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning:  9,63 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier
[0:] MvxBind:Warning:  9,64 Value 'London' was not a known drawable name
[0:] MvxBind:Warning:  9,65 Value 'Paris' was not a known drawable name

Comment: Do you maybe not need to make you `MypageView` class `public` if the converter is a child class? I'm not sure if the converter will be picked up in the sweep to find converters if the class is not public.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are lacking the [android:scaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) in your `ImageView`. Try using `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

If it is not that, try using the `DrawableName` binding instead of `DrawableId` and it's better because you can use a converter in your PCL making it cross-platform with `Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo` and a helper method like this one:

```
public static class CrossDeviceInfoHelper
{
    public static string GetLocalImageUrlByPlatform(string name)
    {
        // Assuming we are working with Android and iOS
        return CrossDeviceInfo.Current.Platform == Platform.Android ? $"@drawable/{name}" : name;
    }
}
```

So you'll endup with a Converter like this one:

```
public class StringToIntValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<string, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == "London")
            return CrossDeviceInfoHelper.GetLocalImageUrlByPlatform("england");
        if (value == "Paris")
            return CrossDeviceInfoHelper.GetLocalImageUrlByPlatform("france");
    }
}
```

Also if I were you I'll add an `enum` or something that tells you the country in your `City` class so that you don't have to compare strings in the converter and you could also have a `Dictionary` in your converter that has which city goes with which country image so that you can just call `CrossDeviceInfoHelper.GetLocalImageUrlByPlatform(myDictionary[value]);` and therefore not using ifs

Comment: Thank you again! I installed `Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo` and tested this solution. I changed `item_city` and `View.cs`. But for some reason, I still can't see icons. I edited my post and added error message

Comment: It works but values are interchanged with each other. How can it be? O_o

Comment: Have you checked the images are named correctly? and the items are correctly set?

Answer (score 0):

The binding expression `DrawableName Name Converter=IconsConverter` is wrong. You are missing a comma:

```
DrawableName Name, Converter=IconsConverter
```

Alternatively you can write it like:

```
DrawableName Icons(Name)
```

Comment: I tried to use `DrawableName Icons(Name)` but the error is ```MvxBind:Error: 10,09 Failed to find combiner or converter for Icons
MvxBind:Warning: 10,09 Value '' could not be parsed as a valid string identifier```

Comment: After that I tried `DrawableName Name, Converter=IconsConverter`, but also have an error. It seems I missed something in names. I'll edit the post